# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'listBox2' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, winforms, window

after entering some text in textbox control (C# window application)and pressing button it will raise two events one is button click and another is my application defined event. im not able to catch the event. and im getting this error. how to solve this ... pls help..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this thread. I hope it helps you out:

[Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t)

Comment: I hope a short and simple tutorial will also do:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GenericCrossThread.aspx